# JPA - multiple persistence units

Tags: jpa, persistence, openjpa, jta, persistence.xml

I'm using JPA and I am connecting to multiple databases. Below is the persistence.xml -

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myRead" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="myWrite" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.test.model.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When the Spring context is loading it is trying to find `Person` table from `myRead` persistence unit. Spring is not recognizing the second persistence unit at all. Can somebody please help.

Comment: exclude-unlisted-classes if you don't want some class available in a particular persistence unit

Comment: The problem is Spring context is not loading the second persistent unit at all. It is trying to find 'Person' table from 'myRead' persistent unit configured with a different database. It throws Exception as 'Table not found'.

Comment: why should it "load" a persistence unit just because it is in your persistence.xml??? Unless you share your code that refers to these persistence units then it won't make sense here