# mySql + Sql Server + Spring Jpa

Tags: mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

This is more of a Q/A kind of question, i am looking for an example to replicate and learn.

Is there a way to use two different database at different servers from my spring application.

Currently my project uses MySql internally, so i have no issues to bind my JPA repositories or Entities file. It uses the database without any problem. 
The problem is that i want to use one entity class that is a table in Sql server (entirely different from the mysql database that i am using currently for all entitiy class).

Please can you provide me example or the steps to be taken towards accomplishing this. I just want to point my Entity class to different database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706508/jpa-multiple-persistence-units

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole example [there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources).

You basically create 2 spring configurations, each defining its own DataSource bean.

Comment: can i just point to different configuration in my entity class?

Comment: Your entity class should never know anything about your spring configuration and datasource. It's the opposite way : you create data access objects, bound to a specific configuration/datasource, that uses those entities when performing a query.